# Warning in converting JAR file into .DLL using IKVM

Tags: java, asp.net

I need to used openForecast.jar in my asp.net app, for that i read here and there and found IKVM, when i wrote in cmd

```
ikvmc openForecast.jar
```

then i got warning message like this

```
D:\Bobby\Telkom Project\ikvm-0.44.0.5\bin>ikvmc OpenForecast-0.4.0.jar
Note IKVMC0002: output file is "OpenForecast-0.4.0.dll"
Warning IKVMC0100: class "org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries" not found
Warning IKVMC0100: class "org.jfree.data.time.RegularTimePeriod" not found
Warning IKVMC0100: class "org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesDataItem" not found
Warning IKVMC0111: emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "net.sourceforge.op
enforecast.input.TimeSeriesBuilder.<init>(Lorg.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;)V"
("org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries")
Warning IKVMC0111: emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "net.sourceforge.op
enforecast.input.TimeSeriesBuilder.<init>(Lorg.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;Ljava.
lang.String;)V"
("org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries")
Warning IKVMC0111: emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "net.sourceforge.op
enforecast.input.TimeSeriesBuilder.build()Lnet.sourceforge.openforecast.DataSet;
"
("org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries")
Warning IKVMC0111: emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "net.sourceforge.op
enforecast.input.TimeSeriesBuilder.build(Lorg.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesDataItem
;)Lnet.sourceforge.openforecast.DataPoint;"
("org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesDataItem")
Warning IKVMC0111: emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "net.sourceforge.op
enforecast.output.TimeSeriesOutputter.output(Lnet.sourceforge.openforecast.DataP
oint;Ljava.lang.String;)V"
("org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesDataItem")
```

I also found that openForecast consist of about 6 class files and 3 subFolder which each contains several class files..
I need help why does this happens and how to fix it (since the documentation of IKVM itself still getting me nowhere), thank you

Comment: How do you "link it in"? This information would be helpful, as I have a jar that is calling the missing class at run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First tip: Simply ignore the warnings and use the code. Often Java jars refer to external code that isn't used except for a particular scenario that you don't care about.

The alternative is to find where the org.jfree.data.time classes are supposed to come from and get that jar and link it in (but you'll run the risk that it too has some dangling dependencies).

Comment: -1 for ignoring the warning. I still haven't met a Java developer who wouldn't "ignore the warning". Warnings are there for a reason.